# I Think I Just Messed Up My Whole System, HELP!

Tags: package-management, network-manager, reinstalling

so i was trying to fix some dependency problems with my repositories and stuff and i ran

```
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
```

and this is what happened (some log from the start isnt shown cause that's all i could copy from my terminal)

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10156566/

i killed apt-get cause i just panicked as i saw network manager being removed, so now i just want to reinstall what i removed
and would be happy if someone could explain what that command was going to do

**UPDATE**
i suppose reinstalling a new version would be more logical, thanks for your help anyways

and i would still be happy to understand what was that command going to do if i hadnt killed it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was optimistic about recovering this but having seen your `apt-get update` output, I can see serious issues. You *have* messed up the system at this point and it's uneconomical to do anything but start again.

- You're using 12.10. This has been dead for almost a year. No more updates, repos moved. That's why you're getting so many 404s and so many packages can't be found.
- You've added the Debian Squeeze main repo. While Ubuntu is based on Debian, they aren't directly compatible. Adding an incompatible repository is like injecting the wrong blood type. This is probably the cause of your dependency-related meltdown.

At this point, I'm not sure what's best, you could remove the Debian repo but you'd also need to track down anything you've installed from it (as it'll be conflicting with current Ubuntu's packages). You'll also need to [switch from the other 404-repos to the old-releases server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release). Even after all that, you'll still need to upgrade to 13.04, then 13.10 and then 14.04 before you're back on a supported system with live repos.

So again, I don't think it's economical to rescue. *I* would struggle to rescue a system like this if I was on site. Instead I would:

1. Create a 14.04 live USB on another computer
2. Reboot into that on this computer
3. Rescue my documents, etc to an external drive
4. Do a fresh install of 14.04
5. **Read** when Apt asks me if I want to continue in the future.

That'll take you about 40 minutes. Rescuing will take hours, if it is indeed possible at all.

Comment: i already figured rebooting would be my doom, im lucky i can still access internet :D
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Well that's worrying in itself. What's the output of `sudo apt-get update`? And does the install work after doing that?

Comment: fetched some packages, still not working : Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop, maybe i could install the packages from my installation cd, but since the amount of packages which have been deleted is a lot, i think installing em one by one would be idiotic, so maybe some way to install all base packages?

Comment: When I asked for the output, I meant "Can I have the full output of ... please?" Can you stick it in another pastebin, it's relevant.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10156839/ i think some of the servers are restricted in my country, but i have been surviving without em, so i dont think that would be a problem

Comment: It seems to me that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is very old since it's trying to fetch packages for _Quantal_, which is not longer available. You should change all _Quantal_ entries to an LTS (either _Precise_ or _Trusty_) or a newer release. The package **ubuntu-desktop** is available on [these releases](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-desktop&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: @AliAmeli Having seen that, I think this install is toast. You could probably rescue it with *many* hours work but you'd do much better to just backup your documents and install 14.04.